# Identify when a user has activated account (verified account)

Tags: docusignapi

We have a scenario in which we're trying to create a DocuSign account and send a user a document to sign nearly simultaneously. However, as we're using the part 11 compliance module, we cannot send a document to a user until they've activated (verified) their account.

Has anyone seen a way to poll or be notified when a user completes their account activation? We're trying to find something to key off of instead of creating the account, then saying, "Please check your email and activate your DocuSign account before continuing," or something a little more hokey from the usability standpoint.

Comment: Are these users being added to a DocuSign account you own/manage?

Comment: Yes, they are being added to our account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- There is no DocuSign connect notification/event that can be sent to indicate that a user has activated their account
- As an alternative, you can take a polling approach and use the REST API to query the /users endpoint to see if the userstatus has changed from activationsent to active. https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Get%20User%20List.htm?Highlight=user